# Accurately measure user interaction time

Tags: javascript

I have an application form (built using c#/web forms/Asp.Net).

The application form is a wizard style - 5 sections - with about 30 assorted input fields split between them and a 'next' button to move onto the following section.

I want to try an accurately measure the time taken to complete the form.

Obviously, I could use Asp's `stopwatch` and record the period between page load and the final button submit, but it wouldn't be entirely accurate.

The reason it wouldn't be accurate is because a user may interrupt the flow - maybe they get interrupted doing something else or go off to find information to fill out the form.

So what I want to do is try to get as an accurate representation as possible. I understand that this is likely to involve javascript because the form is only posted back at the end of each complete section.

However, javascript isn't my language so I'm not sure of the best strategy. I'm not looking for finished solutions, just advice as to a viable approach to achieving what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set events that trigger recording, "mousemove", "focus" and "change". Listen mousemove on the document and the others on the input elements. When they fire, store a value somewhere `mydata={}`;
- On the first fire of any of them, store `{start:event.timeStamp,lastTriggered:event.timeStamp,accumulated:0}`
- On the next consecutive dispatches, do not touch start field anymore, but update `lastTriggered` with event.timeStamp, IF `event.timeStamp - mydata.lastTriggered` was smaller than a threshold (let's say 10000 milliseconds), then set accumulated to `mydata.accumulated += event.timeStamp - mydata.lastTriggered`. Finally, update `mydata.lastTriggered = event.timeStamp`
- on submit stringify the `mydata` and send to server

Comment: After posting I started to make some notes as to what I thought might be feasible - turns out to be exactly what you have confirmed.

Comment: No problem :)))

Answer (score 1):

This is not a technical answer, but rather a 'help you get on your way' one.

You can use local storage for that if you want it on the users side. You will need to frequently send the info to your back-end as well if you want results from uncompleted forms.

---

1. Calculate a visit ID for the user
2. Add the start date time to the local storage with the ID associated to it
3. Frequently (every 5 seconds or so) update the end time in the local storage

If the form breaks / user disconnects:

1. Calculate a new visit ID if the user comes back
2. Set the start datetime for the new visit ID
3. Set the end date time for the new visit ID

---

On form completion, calculate the time between those iterations. Add them all up and you have got yourself a complete log of the users actions in the form, including information on when the users disconnected (and you might want that information to check if the form works appropriately).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following structure:

```
<form class="eform">
  <input name="" />
  <input name="" />
  ...
  <input name="" />
</form>
```

You have a few of options.
*When the user starts filling the form?* for example, when clicks (focus the mouse on) any of the form inputs.
And finish, when the submit button is clicked, or, better, when the submit event of that form is fired:

```
var start=0, end;
$('.eform input').on('focus', function(e){
  start=Date.now()
})

$(document).on('submit','.eform', function(e){
   end=Date.now()-start;
   console.log("Seconds filling the form", parseFloat(end/1000).toFixed(2) )
});
```